# healpy synfast: how to define the random seed

Tags: healpy

I'm using healpy.synfast to create maps, but it seems that healpy does not have the "iseed" function (as in here: http://healpix.jpl.nasa.gov/html/facilitiesnode14.htm) which let me define the random seed to be used for the generation of alms from the power spectrum.

Could anyone tell me how to achieve the "iseed" function in healpy? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`healpy` internally uses `np.random.standard_normal` to generate the real and imaginary components of the `alms`, see [`sphtfunc.py`](https://github.com/healpy/healpy/blob/master/healpy/sphtfunc.py#L308).

Therefore you can use the [`numpy.random.seed`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html) function to set the seed, as:

```
numpy.random.seed(1234)
```

before running `synfast`.